Use a single Image Texture node with multiple mappings
How can I use a single Image Texture node with multiple mappings? The proposed solution for this question does not work in the latest Blender versions. I need to use it like this as shown below. Is there any other solution?


Hello, yes, use a node group plugged into the image node and duplicate the node group

Imagine that you go to a phone booth, read a phone book, and find a phone number for John Doe. You write the number down and bring the note back home. At home, you decide that you want to somehow alter this phone number to call John Smith. You can't. In this analogy, what "Image Texture" outputs is a phone number, and its input is the name. An Image texture doesn't return some kind of array of colors, it just returns a color of a single pixel sampled using the input coordinate, that's it.

Here are the steps to use the same image texture with multiple mapping, using Node Groups :

Select your image texture
⎈ CtrlG to make a new group, it will open the group
↹ Tab to exit the group
Now you can duplicate your node group with ⇧ ShiftD. Everything inside it will be linked, and you'll see a number representing how many copies of this group are present.
Plug any mapping you want through any of the copies of the group
If at some point you want to make one of these copies a unique one, unlinked, click the number just beside the name.



I was trying to create something like that but as it is in the question - a node with an input for the image so that you can already see what image texture you have plugged in there, without the need to look inside the group and being able to change it from the outside. Unfortunately the Image Texture node has no color input or something like that so I have no idea how to do that best. The node group should have some node inside with a color and vector input which can be connected with the group input.

I don't see how it could be possible, as you said Image Texture doesn't have a color input. Maybe a way of remapping the image ? But I don't think it is of any use to have the Image Texture visible outside the group (subjective).

If you only have one group with one image texture in your project, it does not matter - you cannot mistake it for anything. If you use this for multiple images, then knowing which group you have to add in your setup might be helpful. Of course you could name the group after the image, but this would mean you have to rename it whenever you might want to switch the image.

I'm respectfully of the opposite view. I prefer having a string text representing my image (which I can choose freely) than a path name with lots of useless informations. It goes the same for the 3 parameters of Image Textures, I almost never change it afterwards so it's a gain of energy not to have it visible at all times. Anyway, that's probably too subjective and not really in the topic of this question.

@Lutzi for kbd formatting, I think you would be interested to try our community-made userscript to make them easier to do and prettier :)

@Lutzi Well, as I said, I use custom nodegroups as well. Only in this case I think, if it were just a very limited number of textures (one for example), it might be just as easy to simply duplicate the Image Texture node. But this is more a critique on the OP and question itself than on your solution.

Based on the graph OP provided, I suspect this is not what he wanted - and yet, this is the only interpretation that has a valid answer… Well maybe except for figuring out the "Y" in the XY Problem
